# Change the values of a Dictionary for the values of nested dictionaries in it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a doubt, and it is if I can make that a dictionary that have dictionaries as values, can take the values of this nested dictionaries and make them its values.

Example:

```
 d = {"D": {"32_4": 8, "56_7": 4}, "F": {"23_6": 7, "50_7": 0}}
```

Change it to this:

```
 {"D": [8, 4], "F": [7, 0]}
```

So the first dictionary now only contains the values of the nested dictionaries.

Comment: `{k: list(v.values()) for k, v in d.items()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
d = {"D": {"32_4": 8, "56_7": 4}, "F": {"23_6": 7, "50_7": 0}}
d = {key: list(val.values()) for key, val in d.items()}
```

Litteraly : "For each key and its corresponding value in `d`, associate to the key the list of all values in these values"